# Parsing cookies with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, cookies, io

I am trying to properly read cookies on my node server that were set by me through the browser console on localhost:3000 like this:

```
document.cookie = "tagname = test;secure";
document.cookie = "hello=1"
```

In my node server, I use sockets.io, and when I get a connection request, I can access a property which goes like this:

```
socket.request.headers.cookie
```

It's a string, and I always see it like this:

```
'io=QhsIVwS0zIGd-OliAAAA' //what comes after io= is random.
```

I've tried to translate it with various modules but they can't seem to parse the string. this is my latest attempt:

```
var cookie = require('cookie');

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) { 
    socket.on('addUser', function(){
        var a = socket.request.headers.cookie;
        var b = cookie.parse(a); //does not translate
        console.log(b);
    });
}
```

I obviously want to get an object with all the cookies that were sent by each io.connect on the browser.
I've been trying to solve it for 5 hours and I really don't know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: client being what? I did not define anything that is called "client". when I paste that line I get "client is not defined"

Comment: Sorry, Please ignore

Comment: @user1938653 you can send object from client to server in URL also(io.connect('localhost:3000?{key:value}')), at backend, you can get object from URL in socket middleware.

Comment: @KlwntSingh not a good idea since you will have to reestablish the Socket connection everytime you want to change the  value of the URL params.

Answer (score 15):

Use the [Cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie) module. It is exactly what you are looking for.

```
var cookie = require('cookie');
```

cookie.parse(str, options)
Parse an HTTP Cookie header string and returning an object of all cookie name-value pairs. The str argument is the string representing a Cookie header value and options is an optional object containing additional parsing options.

```
var cookies = cookie.parse('foo=bar; equation=E%3Dmc%5E2');
// { foo: 'bar', equation: 'E=mc^2' }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 6):

Without Regexp

```
//Get property directly without parsing
function getCookie(cookie, name){
    cookie = ";"+cookie;
    cookie = cookie.split("; ").join(";");
    cookie = cookie.split(" =").join("=");
    cookie = cookie.split(";"+name+"=");
    if(cookie.length<2){
        return null;
    }
    else{
        return decodeURIComponent(cookie[1].split(";")[0]);
    }
}
//getCookie('foo=bar; equation=E%3Dmc%5E2', 'equation');
//Return : "E=mc^2"
```

Or if you want to parse the cookie to object

```
//Convert cookie string to object
function parseCookie(cookie){
    cookie = cookie.split("; ").join(";");
    cookie = cookie.split(" =").join("=");
    cookie = cookie.split(";");

    var object = {};
    for(var i=0; i<cookie.length; i++){
        cookie[i] = cookie[i].split('=');
        object[cookie[i][0]] = decodeURIComponent(cookie[i][1]);
    }
    return object;
}

//parseCookie('tagname = test;secure');
//Return : {tagname: " test", secure: "undefined"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using socket.handshake instead of socket.request

Comment: Just did, I see something in the same format meaning it's the same.

Comment: Could someone please explain why to use socket.handshake vs socket.request?

Answer (score 1):

The IO cookie is the default cookie socket.io uses as a user id. You can set this but if you don't it will create one and set a hash value to it.
[Read about the option here.](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io#methods-1)

I don't think it is a code issue. Here is an example of your code. When I added the cookie test and set it to 1

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var cookie = require('cookie')
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('chat message', function(){
        var a = socket.request.headers.cookie;
        var b = cookie.parse(a); //does not translate
        console.log(b);
    });
});

http.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});
```

Server Output

```
{ io: 'TxvLfvIupubZpOaGAAAF', test: '1' }
```

If I changed the it to this.

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http, {
  cookie : 'id'
});
```

The output would change this to.

```
{ id: 'ZJPSwFsQAje0SrgsAAAD', test: '1' }
```